# CAST y CONVERT redondean un float al pasarlo a varchar - SQL SERVER 2014 - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio versión 12.0.2269.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Buenas tardes,
Tengo un inconveniente cuando tomo los valores float de una Base de datos sql server y los convierto a varchar con CONVERT. Esta funcion, me redondea el float y luego lo convierte redondeado. Lo mismo ocurre con CAST.
Necesito que el varchar sea una copia fiel del numero float (Con todos los decimales).
Probe poniendo en cada funcion el valor desde una variable (ahi es donde lo redondea y sin variable donde no lo redondea . Adjunto un ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como logro que no lo redondee si el valor esta en una variable????
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?, por favor usa las etiquetas apropiadas

Comment: No puedo utilizar etiquetas apropiadas porque me indica la pagina que tengo que tener 300 puntos de reputacion para utilizarlas.

Comment: es tu post, puedes etiquetarlo con cualquier etiqueta existente. Al menos entonces dinos qué versión de SQL Server estás usando para etiquetarlo nosotros con lo que corresponda

Comment: Agregue los datos en el titulo. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal es que el tipo de datos que quieres convertir es `float`, que es un tipo de datos numérico aproximado. Como estás usando SQL Server 2014, tienes disponible la función `FORMAT`:

```
DECLARE @flo float = -34.6919581;

SELECT FORMAT(@flo,'G');
```

El resultado es `-34.6919581` en formato string.

[**Acá hay**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a401263da5448c64cb82a7c741fde8fc) un demo de esto.

Comment: Excelente, es lo que estaba buscando! Muchas Gracias Lamak

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice Lamak, el `float` es un dato aproximado si necesitas mantener una precisión deberías modificar el tipo a `decimal` por ejemplo un `decimal(15,8)`. Para complementar, tienes algunas otras opciones. Veamos algunas:

- **[`CONVERT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)**

A esta función se le puede configurar el parámetro `style` de los `float` a `128`

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, @flo, 128)
```

**Importante**: No uses esta forma, solo la indico a titulo informativo, según la documentación `126, 128, 129  Included for legacy reasons and might be deprecated in a future release.`

- **`CAST` previo a `decimal`**

Puedes "castear" previamente el `float` a `decimal`con la precisión que busques, por ejemplo:

```
CAST(CAST(@flo AS DECIMAL(15,8)) AS VARCHAR(30))
```

Seguramente esta opción es la mejor para versiones antiguas de `SQL server`, no es tu caso.

- **[`STR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql)**

Esta función está disponible desde la versión `2008` y da un mejor control sobre la representación en caracteres de un `float` ya que permite establecer la longitud y la precisión:

```
STR(@flo, 15,8)
```

De todas las formas me sigo quedando con la propuesta de Lamak ya que no te agrega `0` a la izquierda, ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @flo FLOAT = -34.6919581

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, @flo, 128),
    CAST(CAST(@flo AS DECIMAL(15,8)) AS VARCHAR(30)),
    STR(@flo, 15,8), 
    FORMAT(@flo,'G')

CONVERT       CAST DECIMAL  STR             FORMAT
------------ -------------- --------------- -----------
-34.6919581    -34.69195810    -34.69195810 -34.6919581
```

Comment: Excelente tu explicación Patricio! Muchas Gracias!